# Homogeneity of partials implies the function is homogeneous up to a constant?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function such that the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ are both homogeneous of degree $n \neq 0$. Does it follow that $f(x,y)=g(x,y) +c$, where $g(x,y)$ is homogenous of degree $n+1$

This question has come up in my attempt to solve an ODE's question. My intuition (as well as a few examples) have lead me to believe this is true.

If it is true I would have that $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(0,0)$ but I'm not sure how to show such a function must exist.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both partial derivatives are homogeneous of same order $n$ then both partial derivatives of  $f(tx,ty)-t^{n+1}f(x,y)$ are $0$ and hence $f(tx,ty)-t^{n+1}f(x,y)=h(t)$ for some function $h$. Taking $x=y=0$ we get $h(t)=a-at^{n+1}$ where $a =f(0,0)$. From this we get $g(tx,ty)=t^{n+1}g(x,y)$ if $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(0,0)$.